# Suppose $d(P, Q) = d(R, S)$. Prove that $d(P, R) = d(Q, S)$.

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation

Working on the book: Lang, Serge & Murrow, Gene. "Geometry - Second Edition" (p. 46)

> **6**. In the Figure 1.60, $d(P, Q) = d(R, S)$. Prove that $d(P, R) = d(Q, S)$.

[image]

The answer given in the Solutions manual, is:

> Since $d(P,Q) = d(R,S)$ we can add $d(Q,R)$ to both sides of this equation and obtain
> $$
> \begin{align}
>   d(Q,R) &= d(P,Q) + d(Q,R) \tag{by SEG postulate}\\
>          &= d(R,S) + d(Q,R) \tag{by assumption}\\
>          &= d(Q,S) \tag{by SEG postulate}
> \end{align}
> $$

As I see it, $d(Q,R)$ is not equal to $d(P,Q) + d(Q,R)$. What's the equality the author is using to add $d(Q,R)$?

Comment: Printing mistake, that should probably be $d(P,R)$.

Comment: Thank you. So, it would be $$\begin{align}
  d(P,R) &= d(P,Q) + d(Q,R) \tag{by SEG postulate}\\
         &= d(R,S) + d(Q,R) \tag{by assumption}\\
         &= d(Q,S) \tag{by SEG postulate}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Yes, now it is fine!

Comment: Do you know what term is adding to both sides of the equation ? In the comment I just posted, I cannot locate it.

Comment: Nothing is adding to both sides of the equation. In the first, $PR$ breaks into $PQ + QR$. In the second , $PQ$ becomes $RS$, and in the third, $QR+RS$ becomes $QS$.

Comment: Thank you. I was misled by the comment in the book where it says "we can add (,)
$d(Q,R)$ to both sides of this equation and obtain...". Now, it is clear.

Comment: You are welcome! (Case closed) you can write an answer , accept it and close the question.